# How to resize textarea depending on the parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

So I need to resize the textarea in this form to take the whole available space in the box depending on the parent element (#wrapper). How do I do that?

I will exactly put the negative number calculation more precise when I am sure how much text will go there.

The calculation code I wrote in, calculates height of textarea to 0px.

```js
var boxHeight = ($("#wrapper").height()-200);

$( window ).ready(function(){
    $("#Box").height( boxHeight );
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>XxX</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <h1 class="alignCenter"> Hello </h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris porta egestas urna ac lobortis. Nam bibendum purus sagittis odio fermentum dapibus. Praesent venenatis justo eget hendrerit finibus. Sed rutrum eget lacus a pulvinar. Nulla sit amet faucibus ligula. Curabitur eget nunc finibus, pharetra libero vitae, eleifend sapien. Ut porttitor vehicula arcu, non porttitor tellus faucibus ut.</p>
  <form class="form" id="Form">
   <p class="text">
    <textarea name="text" id="Box" placeholder="Xyz"></textarea>
   </p>
   <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lec2wYTAAAAAOL3DSuOJaSKO8Fk-6lM-VBSCWOx"></div>
   <div class="alignCenter">
    <button class="brown" type="submit">Save</button>
    <button class="purple" type="submit">Publish</button>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If is horizontal use `width:100%` if is vertical `height:100%` (needs 100% is parent)

Comment: Use document instead of window ready. And make the calculation inside document ready.

Comment: The  `#wrapper` block will take on a height to enclose the header, the paragraph and the form, which in turn contains the textarea and the buttons. Unless you have set a height to the `#wrapper` explicitly, there is nothing to calculate. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that `#wrapper` will have a specified height, the you use CSS to get a reasonable fit for the textarea.

First, specify a value for the height in the `#wrapper` rule.

Then, set a height for `#Form` by using absolute positioning and the CSS `calc` function to set the form to be the height of the parent minus 200px.

You then need to do a similar trick to the `p` element wrapping the textarea, leaving 50px height for the buttons.

Finally, set height and width to 100% for `#Box`, and set `box-sizing: border-box` to take into account the border of the textarea element.

**Comment:** Although this can be done, the approach depends on two hard-coded values for the height of the text before the form and the height of the buttons.  JavaScript/jQuery may be the better approach.  Either way, `#wrapper` needs a height value.

```css
#wrapper {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
#Form {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    height: calc(100% - 200px);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
#Form p {
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    margin: 0;
}
#Box {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
     <h1 class="alignCenter"> Hello </h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris porta egestas urna ac lobortis. Nam bibendum purus sagittis odio fermentum dapibus. Praesent venenatis justo eget hendrerit finibus. Sed rutrum eget lacus a pulvinar. Nulla sit amet faucibus ligula. Curabitur eget nunc finibus, pharetra libero vitae, eleifend sapien. Ut porttitor vehicula arcu, non porttitor tellus faucibus ut.</p>
    <form class="form" id="Form">
        <p class="text">
            <textarea name="text" id="Box" placeholder="Xyz"></textarea>
        </p>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lec2wYTAAAAAOL3DSuOJaSKO8Fk-6lM-VBSCWOx"></div>
        <div class="alignCenter">
            <button class="brown" type="submit">Save</button>
            <button class="purple" type="submit">Publish</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Great idea but I don't know the size of the #wrapper. Wrapper changes if you resize the browser with this code `var boxHeight = ($("#wrapper").height()-200);`. So wrapper is 200px less than window size.

Comment: @BarisSarac So you want the `#wrapper` to be the height of the browser minus 200px? and if that is the case, you want the textarea to take any space left after accounting for `h1`, `p` and the buttons? Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this with CSS alone:

```
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This is making the box 60px height.